# Is there a way to get the response from a user when they click on the pop up message created when they close the window?

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight

So I have a Silverlight project and in this Silverlight project I have a C# file where in one of the methods I use the following code to call a Javascript function:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("closeApplication");
```

The closeApplication function is as follows:

```
function closeApplication() 
{
    window.close();
}
```

This produces the pop message that says:

The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window.

Do you want to close this Window?

Yes    No

I want to know if there is a way to get the users response because if it's no. In my c# file after I call the HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("closeApplication"); function, I want to call a different method in that c# file.

Comment: Why not just call it after `window.close()` If they clicked yes it shouldn't run.

Comment: Parton my ignorance as I'm new to Javascript how would I call my c# function from JavaScript?

Comment: You're already running a javascript function `closeApplication`. in that function run more JS after `window.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just cancel event close:

Try this:

```
   MessageBoxResult result = 
                      MessageBox.Show(
                        msg, 
                        "Data App", 
                        MessageBoxButton.YesNo, 
                        MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                    if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
                    {
                        // If user doesn't want to close, cancel closure
                        e.Cancel = true;
                    }
```